# Can't see validation errors from partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Have a partial view containing a form, but can't seem to get validation errors to show up.

**Models**

```
public class HomeModel
{
    public LoginModel LoginModel { get; set; }
}

public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@model MyApp.Models.HomeModel

@{                
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_LoginPartial", Model.LoginModel);
}
```

**HomeController**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new HomeModel()
    {
        LoginModel = new LoginModel()
    });
}        

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    return View("Index", new HomeModel()
    {
        LoginModel = model
    });
}
```

**_LoginPartial**

```
@model MyApp.Models.LoginModel
<form asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Home" method="post" role="form" style="width:70%;margin: 0 auto;">
    <div style="display:none" asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All" class="alert alert-danger fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <strong>Error!</strong> A problem has been occurred while submitting your data.
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left">
        <label asp-for="Username" style="font-size:22px;" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Username" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align:left">
        <label asp-for="Password" style="font-size:22px;" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="spacer-15"></div>
    <div class="form-group" style="font-size:22px;">
        <button type="submit"
                style="background-color: Transparent;
                        background-repeat:no-repeat;
                        border: none;
                        cursor:pointer;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        outline:none;" value="Login">
            <img src="~/images/flower.png" />Next
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What version of MVC is this?

Comment: @Chad version is 6.0 rc1

Comment: @rashfmnb - it's there, can you not see it?

Comment: @rashfmnb OP comment said MVC 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a few things. Each of your inputs will need a corresponding validation element that uses asp-validation-for.

```
<div class="form-group" style="text-align:left">
    <label asp-for="Username" style="font-size:22px;" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Username" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Likewise, if you're planning on using jQuery validation, you should add the following to the environment elements in your _Layout.cshtml file.

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sure enough. I had thought I had put asp-validation-for in there, but I must have deleted it at some point.